# Is my open graph type being pulled into my meta title?

Tags: meta-tags, open-graph-protocol

I have a client whose meta data and open graph tags look like the below but their meta title is showing up as "Article example title" in Google search results. I'm wondering if the og:type is being pulled in somehow and why that would be the case. Does Article need to be lowercase?

This is only happening for a handful of their articles while all of the articles are coded the same. Any help would be great!

```
<title>example title | Brand</title>
<meta name="description" content="example description"/>
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />



<meta property="og:type" content="Article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="example title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="example description" />
```

Comment: While "article" should indeed be lowercase, that shouldn't be the reason why your search engine results are affected. OG meta is mostly for Facebook, Twitter, and other social; Google should be drawing from the usual meta tags. Could be a CMS issue, or it's rewriting your title tags into what it thinks they should be.